# Как записать мне это в одну строку?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Я хочу записать данный код в одну строку:

```
for letter in letters_guess_arg:
    if letter in self.world:
        letters_guess_arg.append(letter)
```

Comment: `letters_guess_arg = [letter for letter in letters_guess_arg if letter in self.world]`

Comment: https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/list-comprehensions-in-python тут можно почитать про синтаксис list comprehension

Comment: @МихаилАлексеевич а в чем минус list comprehension? Работает быстрее читается проще.

Answer (score 0):

Плохие новости. В таком варианте цикл будет бесконечный. Вы берете первый элемент из `letters_guess_arg`, допустим он есть в `self.world`, тогда в конец `letters_guess_arg` добавляется `letter`. Цикл `for` прошелся по первоначальным элементам (до `append`), далее встретил первый элемент, о котором мы говорили, снова добавил его, снова проверил и т.д.